# Drupal 7 how to send drupal_email only BCC without to addres

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to send email only Bcc no need to address. is it passible in Drupal 7 drupal_mail()

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can send BCC email in D7.

here is sample code you can try:

```
$cc = 'ccmail@mail.com';
$bcc = 'bccmail@mail.com';
$to = '';
$from = 'tomail@mail.com';
$params = array(
  'body' => 'Body Message',
  'subject' => 'Your Subject',
  'headers' => array(
    'Cc' => $cc, // optional
    'Bcc' => $bcc, // optional
  ),
);

drupal_mail('mymodule', 'key', $to, $lang, $params, $from);
```

This will send email to all the email address mentioned in Bcc/cc and `$to` would be blank.

or you can simply add mutiple email ids without space in `$to` for individual mail

```
$to = 'emailone@mail.com,emailtwo@mail.com';
```

Or Refere this Post - https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6677/how-to-programmatically-send-an-email

hope this will help you.